# How to get the total storage of all previous version objects in an S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

For a version enabled bucket, I would like to see how much storage takes for current version vs. previous version in a s3 bucket. Currently I can only get the total storage size for a bucket including both current version and previous version

Comment: How are you currently obtaining the total storage size? Are you using the metrics from Amazon CloudWatch? There is no pre-provided way to list the size of only "current versions". You would need to write some code, or use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) to obtain a complete listing and then calculate the size. Let us know if you have any difficulties writing the code.

Comment: Correct, I could not find metrics related to versions. Because the bucket is huge, list-object-versions would take a long time to compute the size.

Answer (score 0):

Since you wish to retrieve information on the objects in a "huge" bucket, I would recommend using [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily CSV file containing information about all objects in the bucket.

If your requirement is just one-off, you could turn it off after a day.

The [Amazon S3 inventory report](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html#storage-inventory-contents) says:

> You can configure what object metadata to include in the inventory, **whether to list all object versions or only current versions**, where to store the inventory list file output, and whether to generate the inventory on a daily or weekly basis.